# Does bubble-phonon-bubble diagram matter for conductivity of electron-phonon system?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, phonons

In linear response, electrical conductivity due to electron-phonon coupling (EPC) is calculated by using the Kubo formula. Typically, electronic self-energy due to such coupling is included, and such dressed electron Green function is used in the simplest bubble diagram below of Kubo formula (wavy line is external electromagnetic field). For instance, this is followed in [paper1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.4248), [paper2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2578), [paper3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3514v1), etc. and also introduced in Mahan's book 'Many particle physics'.

[image]

I think in this self-energy way, the leading EPC effect is $O(g^2)$ with $g$ the EPC strength, which is contributed by the above bubble with, e.g., an upper electron line dressed by one phonon and a lower bare hole line in the bubble and vice versa.

But one can also think of two electron-hole bubbles connected by a phonon line (dashed).
This diagram with one phonon is also $O(g^2)$. Why is it excluded?
They seem to be in the same order.
[image]

Comment: Why do you suggest that they are the last diagram is $\mathcal{O}(g^2)$? There are two fermion-phonon vertices. Don't they contribute to the order of the coupling $g$?

Comment: @schris38 The rule is any internal phonon line gives $g^2$ since $g$ is the coupling constant between electron field and phonon field.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking, but if $g$ is the coupling constant between the electron field and the phonon field, shouldn't $g$ be assigned to each vertex?

Comment: If it is as you say, then your first diagram is $\mathcal{O}(g^0)$, no? There are no phonons there afterall

Comment: @schris38 Yes, assigned to each vertex, and there are two vertices and hence $g^2$. For your second question, see the paragraph above and below the first figure: One can replace the bare lines with ones dressed by a phonon.